# How does a ring paper airplane fly for a long distance?

Tags: aerodynamics, glider, paper-airplane

My friend showed me something which he called the glider. At a first look, it looks like it will crash, but it flew quite well:

[image]

I was surprised to see it go about 25 meters (82 feet), as it was nothing but a big ring made out of paper. I thought of how it could fly, but I had no idea. I knew that it could go through air with least resistance, but it wasn't supposed to fly.

Can someone explain me the logic of how this flies?

Comment: Was the paper heavier at the front, either by folding or by adding a paperclip?

Comment: @PeterKämpf, nope, there was nothing. It was the same throughout.

Comment: @mins. Mm, actually I am an absolute beginner. I don't know the difference. Basically my friend just held the ring in his hand, and threw it. He held the curved paper part in his hand. Also, it is not launched in rotation.

Comment: @mins, no the youtube video, this is different. The one I have posted in my question uses an A4 size paper cut into half (by length) and the edged joined by glue. Also, I think the throw was axial.

Comment: I saw something similar to this before as one of my friends rolled a piece of paper up into a cone and it "flew" well too.

Comment: The edge of the ring facing the viewer on your picture is opposite to flight direction, right? If you look closely, you can see that the far edge has been folded onto itself to add some weight at the front. Dare your friend to throw it holding it "backwards": If it would be the same throughout, it would still fly. I bet it won't.

Comment: @Peter Kämpf It looks to me like the same thing has been done at both ends of the cylinder.

Comment: @Peter Kämpf  I'm wrong about that. There's a [video](https://youtu.be/bYYbtM-iRr4) on how to make it.  Several folds in front. Half of the weight of the paper is in the front edge.

Comment: [Demonstrated on TV show QI (2:00 onwards)](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=lsjdGLwZ1a8)

Comment: I play with these and in order to fly you need to add a little rotation. The rotation adds a gyroscopic effect and prevents tumbling in the same way that the  rifling in a gun barrel adds rotation to a bullet to stop it from tumbling. Experiment for yourself and try making one (with a leading edge fold for weight) and try it with and without spin.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No takers? Then I'll bite.

[This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14283/how-do-paper-airplanes-create-lift-if-their-wings-are-flat) addresses how paper airplanes generate lift. This lift is caused by higher pressure on the lower side and lower pressure (suction) on the upper side, and if both are added up, the chordwise pressure distribution is shown below:

[image: Flat plate pressure distribution]

Flat plate pressure distribution (picture [source](http://www.windsofkansas.com/atoz2.html))

If you collect all the local forces in one point, the lift acts at a quarter of the wing's chord. That is why the forward half of the paper which in the end will be bent into the ring needs to be folded onto itself: The center of gravity of the wing is also at one quarter of chord. Thus, the lift and the weight will act a the same station and no pitching moment results.

To achieve a flight distance of 25 m, your friend threw the ring with some force to give it a high initial speed. This speed would allow it to create enough lift with very little angle of attack, so it did not suffer from flow separation initially. This resulted in low drag and the high launch speed gave the ring some kinetic energy.

Friction slowed the ring down gradually, but the decrease in lift at lower speed was compensated by a gradual increase of the ring's angle of attack. Why would the angle be just right to prevent the ring both from rising and dropping, you might ask? Any imbalance between lift and weight would add a vertical acceleration which would immediately change the angle at which the ring hits the flow. Its chord length and inertia would prevent it from rotating nose up or down, so it would pretty much stay on its initial path until most of the speed was eaten up and the angle of attack was so high that separation sets in. At this point, the drag would go up and speed up the deceleration process, and the ring would sink to the ground.