# Why did a circular paper aeroplane of larger diameter fly further than one of a smaller diameter?

Tags: aerodynamics

http://www.10paperairplanes.com/how-to-make-paper-airplanes/07-the-ring.html
I am not an expert at this- just a high school student, so please explain this in fairly simple terms. Thank-you very much in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does a ring paper airplane fly for a long distance?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24782/how-does-a-ring-paper-airplane-fly-for-a-long-distance)

Comment: That question explains how it flies, but not its relation to size, so it is definitely *not* a duplicate.

Comment: Related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/50597/does-anyone-know-an-equation-relating-wingspan-to-gliding-distance-for-a-glider/50617#50617

Comment: It would be helpful if you can include a picture of what a "circular paper airplane" is in the question instead of linking to a website.

Answer (score 6):

The larger glider flies with a larger [Reynolds number](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/36678/how-does-reynolds-number-affect-skin-friction-drag/36683#36683), so friction drag will be lower relative to lift.

Using paper of the same grammage (weight per area) would result in the same wing loading and the same flight speed, and the Reynolds number will grow linearly with glider size. If you look up in the linked answer how friction drag changes with Reynolds number, you will see that friction drag drops with increasing Reynolds numbers.