# Could box-wing aircraft be the plane of the future

Tags: wing, winglets

I've read that box-wing aircraft can reduce wingtip vortices caused by induced drag hence saving up a lot of fuel and hence able to carry more passengers. Would we able to see such aircraft in the near future?

Comment: This is a highly speculative question (as any question trying to predict the future)

Comment: See also: [How does the wraparound wing design reduce drag?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/52092/14897)